# Update woocommerce price of a product based on php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom add to cart button in php for a single product:

```
Final total<br>
            $<?php echo $row['purchase-price'] ?>.00<br><br>
            <button onclick="window.location.href='https://yourdomain.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=362166';">Add to cart</button>
```

After clicking the button, it returned a "Sorry, this product cannot be purchased." error. I havent set the product price since the amount in `<?php echo $row['purchase-price'] ?>` is always changing. How to pass the amount set in php and pass it to product's final price?

Comment: setup the quantity params behind your URL like `checkout/?add-to-cart=362166&quantity=3`.  if you want to pass the price from the URL then everyone could set the price when they send the add-to-cart request. Instead of insecurity way, the idea is set up the addtocart hook and parse the params to calculate before adding to the cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First you will restrict your code to single product and archives pages only:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 'double_price', 10, 2 );

function double_price( $price, $product ){
    if( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() || is_product() ) {
        global $wpdb;
        //your query to get price from custom db
        //FOR GET PRODUCT ID $product->get_id();
        $price = $row['purchase-price'];
    }
    return $price;
}
```

2. Then for cart and checkout pages, you will change the cart item price this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item', 'set_custom_cart_item_prices', 20, 2 );
function set_custom_cart_item_prices( $cart_data, $cart_item_key ) {
    global $wpdb;
    //your query to get price from custom db
    $new_price = $row['purchase-price'];

    //FOR GET PRODUCT ID $cart_item['data']->get_id();

    // Set and register the new calculated price
    $cart_data['data']->set_price( $new_price );
    $cart_data['new_price'] = $new_price;

    return $cart_data;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', 'set_custom_cart_item_prices_from_session', 20, 3 );
function set_custom_cart_item_prices_from_session( $session_data, $values, $key ) {
    if ( ! isset( $session_data['new_price'] ) || empty ( $session_data['new_price'] ) )
        return $session_data;

    // Get the new calculated price and update cart session item price
    $session_data['data']->set_price( $session_data['new_price'] );

    return $session_data;
}
```

And in the last hit your custom url

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='https://yourdomain.com/?add-to-cart=362166&quantity=1';">Add to cart</button>
```

Comment: Add to cart URL should be generated using WooCommerce functions

Comment: @Raptor, Thanks for the comment, I know but I comment as per their requirement.

Comment: I was advised to use the 'woocommerce_product_get_price' filter and modify the return value. `<?php echo $row['purchase-price'] ?>` was obtained from a value in a mysql database query. The problem is I don't have any idea yet how to put that into code.

Comment: @RosalitoUdtohan i have updated my answer. Are you looking for this?